# Call a stored procedure with parameters from an Azure runbook

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure, stored-procedures, parameters

I'm trying to call a maintenance SP from within an Azure runbook:

```
   inlinescript {
        .........
        $Cmd = New-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $Cmd.Connection = $Conn
        $Cmd.CommandText = "EXEC [dbo].[BackupLogTable] @tableName, @olderThan"

        $Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", $TableName)
        $Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@olderThan", $OlderThan)

        $Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        .....
    }
```

The SP is declared like this:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[BackupLogTable] (
    @tableName nvarchar(512),
    @olderThan int
)
with execute as owner as
```

and I can successfully run it from SSMS under the same user my runbook uses. But when testing it in Azure portal I'm getting the following error:

> Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The
>   parameterized query '(@tableName  nvarchar(4000),@olderThan
>   nvarchar(4000))EXEC [dbo].' expects the parameter '@tableName', which
>   was not supplied."

I tried every other variants of passing the parameters found on the net like this one:

```
$Cmd.CommandText = "[BackupLogTable]"
$Cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure

$Cmd.Parameters.Add("@tableName", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar, 512) | Out-Null
$Cmd.Parameters["@tableName"].Value = $TableName

$Cmd.Parameters.Add("@olderThan", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int) | Out-Null
$Cmd.Parameters["@olderThan"].Value = $OlderThan
```

and many others but it always fails:

> Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Procedure
>   or function 'BackupLogTable' expects parameter  '@tableName', which
>   was not supplied."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you passing your parameters to your inline script?

There's some limitations; e.g. Get-AutomationVariable / AutomationCredential is not available in the InlineScript.

"The InlineScript activity runs a block of commands in a separate, non-workflow session and returns its output to the workflow. While commands in a workflow are sent to Windows Workflow Foundation for processing, commands in an InlineScript block are processed by Windows PowerShell. The activity uses the standard workflow common parameters including PSComputerName and PSCredential which allow you to specify that the code block be run on another computer or using alternate credentials."

So, there's some limitations on how to pass and get variables.

However you can pass values into the inlinescript using $Using.

E.g: InlineScript { Write-output $using:TableName }

Hopefully that'd do the trick.

See also the recommendations for inlinescript on: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469257(v=sc.16).aspx#bkmk_InlineScript

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know `$using` was required within `inlinescript`.